# How to draw quadratic function using tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-collection

Is it possible to draw the following graph using `tkz-euclide`? The coordinate system looks better to me. I know how to get the coordinates, but not the quadratic function.

The code I have so far is only for the coordinate system:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
\tkzGrid
    \tkzLabelX[orig=true,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzLabelY[orig=false,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzDrawX
    \tkzDrawY
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the code that you have so far. This way the answers will be extensions of your approach and easier to use for you. And we don't have to type all the stuff that you already have.

Comment: Please do not just add a piece of code, but a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2):

With the `tkz-fct` package, use `\tkzFct[<options>]{<function>}`, compile with `--shell-escape` enabled, and I believe you need to have `gnuplot` installed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
\tkzGrid
    \tkzLabelX[orig=true,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzLabelY[orig=false,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzDrawX
    \tkzDrawY
    \tkzFct[domain=-5:0,black]{\x**2-4}
    \tkzFct[domain=0:5,black]{2*\x-4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you'd like a method that doesn't involve `gnuplot` and `shell-escape`, you could try `pgfplots`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-5.5,xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,ymax=5.5,
  axis lines=center,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  grid,
  xtick={-5,...,5},
  ytick={-5,...,5},
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}]

\addplot [black,domain=-5:0] {x^2-4};
\addplot [black,domain=0:5] {2*x-4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @Torbjørn T. I think I just figured it out by using `\draw`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
\tkzGrid
    \tkzLabelX[orig=true,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzLabelY[orig=false,label options={font=\tiny}]
    \tkzDrawX
    \tkzDrawY
    \draw[scale=1, domain=-3:0,smooth,variable=\x,blue, line width = 1pt] plot ({\x},{\x*\x-4});
    \draw[scale=1, domain=0:4.5, smooth, variable=\x, blue, line width = 1pt] plot({\x}, {2*\x-4});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't think about that. (+1)